# Delphi on Windows 10 - Can't debug remote server anymore with TSocketConnection

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-2007, windows-10, multi-tier

I have a 3-tier application that uses TSocketConnection to connect to a remote datamodule server app.

In Windows 8 i could open two instances of Delphi, one for the client and another for the server. I run both inside Delphi and could debug the server app with breakpoints : when the client called a function in the server that has a breakpoint, the execution would stop in this breakpoint inside Delphi's server app.

In Windows 10 this behaviour does not happen anymore. With the same scenario explained above, when i execute the client application it open a new instance of the server application, not using the instance already opened inside Delphi. So i end up with two instances of the server app instead of only one.

Is there a way to go back to the previous behaviour ? It was very useful to debug the server app.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After i post the question i could find what was wrong and will share here, so it can help someone.

It turns out that both instances of opened Delphi (client and server) should run as administrator. In my case i was using Delphi XE for the client and Delphi 2007 for the server, and only Delphi XE was running as administrator.

So when i run Delphi 2007 as admin i could debug the server app as it worked on Windows 8.